# Sequelize Dynamic select attributes? works?

Tags: typescript, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

facing one issue like - is it really possible to pass dynamic select attributes to FindAll method? Its not working as its not getting recognized.

```
selectAttributes= "'x_name','y_name','z_name','start_z'"; //prepare this dynamically
groupBy = ['x_name','y_name','z_name','start_z','start_z']       
const results =  await XX.findAll({
        group:groupBy,           
        attributes:['x_name','y_name','z_name','start_z','start_z',
                                    [Sequelize.fn(Constants.SEQUELIZE_SUM_FUNCTION, 
                                      Sequelize.col(obj.metrics)),obj.metrics]],

        where:result.where , //I have this built dynamically which works great
        order: result.order,//I have this built dynamically which works great

    });
```

//the above code works and gets all columns in select. but  I wanted to pass the columns dynamically along with group and where and order by; I was success with where/orderby/group by but not select attributes. I was making a string and passing it as select attribute but its not recognizing it and returns only SUM column in above code.

How could I generalize the SELECT attributes for FindALL?

Comment: selectAttributes = ['x_name','y_name','z_name','start_z','start_z'] and attributes: [...selectAttributes, [Sequelize.fn(Constants.SEQUELIZE_SUM_FUNCTION, 
                                      Sequelize.col(obj.metrics)),obj.metrics]] does not work?

Comment: select attrributes are part of bigger array like [select attributes, [ ] ]; having trouble in making this array. and we cant pass select attributes alone in array

Comment: and what is a criteria to distingwish select attributes from others in the bigger array?

Comment: Actually I had to use the array split like ...attributes and that helped me to sail through. here attributes is dynamically built array of select columns              attributes:[...attributes,
                                    [Sequelize.fn(Constants.SEQUELIZE_SUM_FUNCTION, 
                                      Sequelize.col(obj.metrics)),obj.metrics]],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possibly this would help others who are looking to build dynamic select attributes.

```
    selectAttributes= build your array here dynamically //prepare this dynamically
groupBy = ['x_name','y_name','z_name','start_z','start_z']       
const results =  await XX.findAll({
        group:groupBy,           
        attributes:[...selectAttributes,                                  [Sequelize.fn(Constants.SEQUELIZE_SUM_FUNCTION,                                       Sequelize.col(obj.tasks)),obj.tasks]],
        where:result.where , //I have this built dynamically which works great
        order: result.order,//I have this built dynamically which works great
    });
```

Comment: This column where you are finding sum, how do you access that value from results array? I tried accessing it directly but it didn't work. And also not working with getDataValue function